# maven - mirror depending on project

Tags: maven, mirror

I have a mirror for maven central setup like this in settings.xml:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>artifactory-other</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://some.internal.site/artifactory/repo</url>
    <name>Artifactory</name>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

But this server is accessible only from the internal network. When I'm at home and tinker with some side projects I need to access the real repositories. For now I just comment this mirror out, but it's cumbersome.

How can I make it automatic? Is it possible to define a profile with separate mirrors and automatically activated based on project path? Is there some simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not using mirror-any, but using specific repository declarations with [dependencies pom cleanups](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories#VirtualRepositories-EnsuringArtifactoryisYourSoleArtifactsProvider).
This way you'll be as protected from going to unauthorized repos as with mirror-any and you'll be able to declare profiles (work and home) with different servers in each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is not an out-of-the-box solution with Maven. Usual i check in my `settings.xml` via git and having different branches for different networks like at work, home etc. The result is reduced to a simple

```
git checkout HOME
```

or

```
git checkout WORK
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

With new maven (3.3.1+), use the [project-settings-extension](https://github.com/gzm55/project-settings-maven-extension#example) to load the project settings, and put project specific mirrors into `${basedir}/.mvn/settings.xml` in each project.

in `${basedir}/.mvn/extensions.xml`

```
    <extensions xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/core-extensions-1.0.0.xsd">
      <extension>
        <groupId>com.github.gzm55.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-settings-extension</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.5</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
```

in `${basedir}/.mvn/settings.xml`

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>id</id>
      <url>https://internal-repo/</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Then the project will be built out-of-box in the internal network with `mvn test`, and not pollute your personal `.m2/settings.xml`